# What is a good way to manage the files your application creates and uses

Tags: windows, installation

I am trying to develop an application which has to store the paths of different folders . I thought I will create a file that stores these paths.

My problem is I don't know a proper way to manage this file like where I should save this file. I looked for information on managing files our application creates but couldn't find it. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can keep file paths in a `txt file` as absolute path of them.

You can pick create a folder under `documents` or some `other folder` then write into your txt file.

I don't get what is so complex about it.

Comment: can I use my installation directory to store my files? I am new to programming so I wanted to be sure whether it is the correct way

Comment: Yes you can use any directory you want. but make sure that you will not `accidentally` delete that directory for any reason.